# Adding values stored in NSString in NSMutableArray for ios

Tags: ios6

I am posting the code which I tried.I am getting string value,but when adding all the values of nsstring to nsmutablearray and printing it ,I get null value.

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
     NSString *stringValueVideoiD;
     NSMutableArray *TableVideoIDArray;
}

//ViewController.m
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   TableVideoIDArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void) getAllRows{

 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM table"];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,[sqlStatement UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
         while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
             char *videoId = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
                stringValueVideoiD = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:videoId];
                [TableVideoIDArray addObject:stringValueVideoiD];
               NSLog(@"vids id:%@",TableVideoIDArray);
           //vids id:(null) is printed
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: `TableVideoIDArray` is `nil` and that is why `vids id:(null)` is printed.  Why it is `nil` is not clear from the code that you posted.  Two main possibilities are (1) that `-getAllRows` is called before `-viewDidLoad` and (2) that `TableVideoIDArray` is set to `nil` sometime after `-viewDidLoad` is called but before `-getAllRows` is called.  If you make `TableVideoIDArray` into a property (right now it's just an ivar), you can set a symbolic breakpoint on `-[ViewController setTableVideoIDArray:]` to figure out when it is getting set.

Comment: Are you sure that stringValueVideoiD printed value?

Comment: yes wesley I am getting stringValueVideoiD printed 2013-09-17 19:09:38.033 APPName[482:11303] vids id:bVkMdSFBNcE
2013-09-17 19:09:38.034 APPName[482:11303] vids id:5TzM_y40l8c
2013-09-17 19:09:38.034 APPName[482:11303] vids id:UBl9taUKj9U

Answer (score 0):

Check if **stringValueVideoiD** has some value. Try to print it before **addObject**. Check you sql statement if it is returning any value.

Comment: I am getting stringValueVideoiD printed .I have posted my console result above.

Comment: I see in above code you are printing TableVideoIDArray. Add a break point in code and see after adding stringValueVideoiD to TableVideoIDArray, what the array count is.

Comment: Just for testing add some hardcoded value to TableVideoIDArray. [TableVideoIDArray addObject:@"Test"]; see if it adds Test value in the array and print it. If true then there is a problem in the string stringValueVideoiD.

Comment: I did like this [TableVideoIDArray addObject:@"test"];
                NSLog(@"vids id:%lu",(unsigned long)[TableVideoIDArray count]); and i am geeting array count 0.

Comment: So strange!!! Try to allocate the array in the getAllRows method. and print it like NSLog(@"vids id: %d",[TableVideoIDArray count]);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37532/discussion-between-mobiletest-and-wimcnilesh)